# How do I use user-secrets for dbcontext with dotnet ef scaffold tool?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In my `appsettings.json` I store the connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDb": "Server=localhost;Database=MYDB;User Id=sa"
}
```

I store the password for this connection as a user-secret as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=linux#enable-secret-storage):

```
dotnet user-secrets set "Password:Database:MyDb" "password-here"
```

In code, I setup the connection using `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`:

```
var conStrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDb"));
conStrBuilder.Password = builder.Configuration["Password:Database:MyDb"];
builder.Services.AddSqlServer<MyDbContext>(conStrBuilder.ConnectionString);
```

Before I moved the password to a user-secret, I was just adding it to the connection string above (i.e. `;Password=password-here`). That meant I could then use the following with the dotnet CLI:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=ConnectionStrings:MyDb Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

Now of course, this returns `Login failed for use 'sa'.`.

Is there a way to separately pass the password on the command line, so I don't have to put the password in source control *or* have it plain on the command line?

Comment: Just put the whole connection string (including password) into your `secrets.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mycah's suggestion worked for me. I had connection stored in secret manager with following structure:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SomeName": "<your_connection_string>"
}
```

The DbContext was setup as:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("name=SomeName");
```